# Does SQL Server repair rollback the buildnumber?

Tags: sql-server-2014

Let's say that my current SQL Server version is 2014 sp1 cu1. I repaired the existing installation using base rtm file. Will that rollback my version to 12.00.2000?

Comment: I dont think so, but you can go ahead and check. Even if it reverts to RTM you can install SP1 and CU1 again.

Comment: Usually a .msi rollback (repair) to its version.